# use dispatch_time to do task periodically

Tags: ios, swift

I try to use dispatch_time to periodically call `doTask()` recursively with a interval of 600 seconds. Here is my simple code:

```
private func doTask() -> Void {
     var interval : NSTimeInterval = someService.getInterval() //it is 600
     NSLog("interval = \(interval)"); //Like I said, it is 600, because I see the log
     let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(interval * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))

      //recursively call doTask() after 600 seconds
      dispatch_after(dispatchTime,
                      GlobalBackgroundQueue,
                      {self.doTask()}
            )
        }
```

Here is the `GlobalBackgroundQueue`:

```
var GlobalBackgroundQueue: dispatch_queue_t {
        return dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND.value), 0)
    }
```

But when I call the `doTask()` function, at runtime, the interval between each call on doTask() is 15 seconds. Why? Why the interval is not 600 seconds?

**=====UPDATE=====**

I also tried NSTimer:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(interval, target: self, selector: "doTask", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

But at runtime, the doTask() get called every 20 seconds. Still not 600 seconds.

Comment: `long interval = 600` does not compile in Swift. Please post your *real* code.

Comment: Sorry, typo. Updated now.

Comment: why dont you use timers?

Comment: Tried also NSTimer, please see my update.

Comment: Rule: Since you can't find the bug, it is somewhere where you were not looking. You refuse to show someService.getInterval(), so that's the most likely place for the bug. You claim it returns 600. Your code doesn't work. Therefore something you believe isn't true.

Comment: @gnasher729 , Please see my update, I say it is 600 because I see it is 600. So, I am pretty sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let delay: UInt64 = 600
let dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * NSEC_PER_SEC))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I updated my question, please take a look. It is a small change. The `delay` is of `NSTimeInterval` type

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
let delay: NSTimeInterval = 600
let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(Double(NSEC_PER_SEC) * delay))
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
})
```